# How to put a dot before a character in a string?

Tags: swift, string

> Input : "bus"
>
> Output: ".b.u.s"

How to print a dot and a character and a dot and a character and so on in a string ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt was made to solve the problem. Please be specific to your problem and add the code only which is cause of an error or issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to put '.' and convert that `array` to `String`.

```
let string = "bus"
let formattedString = String(string.flatMap {".\($0)"})
print(formattedString) //.b.u.s
```

Comment: Alternatively, `let formattedString = string.map {".\($0)"}.joined()`